# Generate the 100th "look and say" number

Tags: python, python-3.x

This program finds the 100th member of the ["look and say" sequence](https://oeis.org/A005150):

> - 1
> - 11 (one 1)
> - 21 (two 1's)
> - 1211 (one 2 and one 1)
> - 111221 (one 1, one 2, two 1's)
> - 312211 etc.

```py
from itertools import groupby, chain 

def _look_and_say(seq: str):
    return ''.join(f"{len(list(g))}{k}" for k, g in groupby(seq))

a = '1'

for i in range(100):
    a = _look_and_say(a)

print(a)
```

---

Obviously I need to replace the loop with proper code.

I was trying to use `functools.reduce`

```py
reduce(lambda x, count: _look_and_say(x), chain('1', range(30)))
```

but that doesn't look good.

Also is there a better way to do this: `len(list(g)` if g is an iterator?

Comment: This is what I'm doing, I was generalizing.

Comment: It Is not at all obvious why for loop Is not a "proper code" And why you need to replace it.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I changed the title so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](/questions/how-to-ask): "*State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.*". Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Comment: @slepic I think OP is looking for an FP approach.

Answer (score 2):

I think iterators are amazing. However not everything should be an iterator, or use comprehensions.
Statements like:

> Obviously I need to replace the loop with proper code.

Only make me see short-sighted snobbishry. Which I only see in the FP vs OOP part of the programming world. Iterators and comprehensions can't and shouldn't be jammed into everything.

---

- The function `_look_and_say` looks pretty good.
- Rather than assigning `i` and never using it, it's commonly accepted to use `_` as a throw away variable.
- Python has a style guide, which a large amount of users follow. This style guide suggests putting two empty lines around top level functions and classes.

  I would recommend you do this too, so that your code looks like everyone elses. Which improves readability for everyone.
- It's best not to have code run in the global scope, just wrap it up in a `main`.
- You should wrap your code in a `if __name__ == '__main__':`, making your code only run if you run the file. As opposed to importing it.

Which results in the following *proper code*:

```py
from itertools import groupby, chain 


def _look_and_say(seq: str):
    return ''.join(f"{len(list(g))}{k}" for k, g in groupby(seq))


def main():
    a = '1'
    for _ in range(100):
        a = _look_and_say(a)
    print(a)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

I would prefer `_look_and_say` to return all look and say numbers, and for main to stop `_look_and_say` when it has reached the number it wants.

To do this I would move the for loop into `_look_and_say` as a `while True:` loop. Change it so you `yield` from the function. And then finally use `itertools.islice()` to extract the desired number, with the `nth` recipe.

```py
import itertools


def look_and_say():
    value = '1'
    while True:
        yield value
        value = ''.join(f"{len(list(g))}{k}" for k, g in itertools.groupby(value))


def nth(iterator, n, default=None):
    return next(itertools.islice(iterator, n , None), default)


def main():
    print(nth(look_and_say(), 100 - 1))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I'm not saying loops shouldn't be used, I wanted to replace this one. I just find `x = f(x)` as an only expression in a loop weird.

Comment: @Kazz Ok. I found your question highly unclear in that regard, and given that in both your questions you've pretty much asked "please make this only use iterators" the perception you gave off didn't help. (And yes you did in this one, as you provided that second piece of code that only used iterators). Good code is no code; `x = f(x)` is no code, so good code.